# Cannot customize my font with my Neve Wordpress Theme. Completely stuck at this point

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the font on my installed Neve theme. It is a custom font so I have to do it manually. I don't want to use a plugin because it slightly increases load times. I tried adding the below code but without success. I also tried adding the same code inside the Customize Theme option under additional CSS. Nothing on the site is changing. I tried even .otf files, messing with the directory and more.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong? How can I change if it is being overwritten? Any help is appreciated!

I used Dreamhosts integrated FTP to add the .woff file inside the theme directory. Then I went into the css stylesheet and entered this:

```
@/font-face {

font-family: Gotham Book;

src: url(fonts/Gotham_Book_Regular.woff');

font-weight: normal;

}



.h1 site-title {

font-family: 'Gotham Book'!important, Arial, sans-serif;

}



.site-title {

font-family: 'Gotham Book'!important, Arial, sans-serif;

}



h1, h2, h3 {

font-family: 'Gotham Book'!important, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Check your console for 404 errors

Comment: I thought 404 errors are when the site isn't able to be reached. The site works fine just the font isn't changing